# Import XmlNode into another XmlNode NOT XmlDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmldocument

I know I can do this :

```
XmlNode newParent = UnitedXml.ImportNode(parentNode, true);
UnitedXml.AppendChild(newParent);
```

where unitedxml is an XmlDocument.

Now I want to import a child into "newParent" (Which does not have ImportNode method) from a different XmlDocument.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 XmlNode impertedNode = UnitedXml.ImportNode(x, true);
 newParent.AppendChild(impertedNode);
```

this was a silly mistake. sorry.